# How to get the embed video and put it in an iframe or popupwindow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

I have a search engine where it will display a list of URL where it will redirect you to the website, how will I only get the video?

here's the list of the example URLs

https://archive.org/details/nazi_concentration_camps

http://www.kumby.com/teekyuu-3-episode-9/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fI3zBtE_S_k

Is there a code in PHP or jquery or javascript? or anything that it will only get the embed video and will display it in iframe or popupwindow or anything? fancybox?

I'm just a new programmer. So please help me. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<iframe id="player1" src="http://www.kumby.com/teekyuu-3-episode-9/?api=1&player_id=player_1" width="500" height="500" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: where did you got the "/?api=1&player_id=player1"  ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry ;

```
<iframe id="player1" src="http://www.kumby.com/teekyuu-3-episode-9/" width="300" height="210" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: but how about the exact video only?

Comment: I'm highly aware this is old, but please edit the first answer rather than posting three separate ones with almost identical content.

Answer (score 0):

you need to take videoUrl and then You will link to the iframe.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/fI3zBtE_S_k" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: oh my . that would take long. because. when search my url it should automatically set my video embed url on each List of links